Is it possible to make a Swift struct implement a Kotlin interface?
Is it possible to make a Swift struct implement a Kotlin interface? For example in Swift:
struct MyStruct : KotlinInterface {
    func...() {}
}

And from Kotlin:
interface KotlinInterface {
    func...()
}

In Kotlin:
__attribute__((swift_name("KotlinInterface")))
@protocol InternalName <Name>
@required
@end

I tried this but it gives the following error:
Non-class type 'MyStruct' cannot conform to class protocol 'KotlinInterface'
Copied from this. This readed. 5 years left after these discussions, maybe something changed.

Non-class type cannot conform to class protocol. Answer is NO. struct can't implement Kotlin interface. Btw why you have irresistible desire to use exactly struct for KotlinInterface conformance?

@Cy-4AH Struct is a Swift way to implement everything. Apple force us to use structs. In our app there are already functional written with structs and change it to class is like downgrade code.

@NikeKov well tough luck then. You need classes to talk with Kotlin.

No it doesn't. Have you seen ObservableObject or Actors?

@NikeKov it's not true that Apple forces you to use struct for everything. You can use a class if you need to.

Look, the question is not how workaround and use ObservableObject, actors or classes with Kotlin protocols. The question is does kotlin allow and have functional to make protocols that can interact with structs

No. it doesn't. Kotlin is using objective-c runtime. In Objective-C all protocols are id's
